# How do I know if one of my RAID 1 drives died?

Tags: raid, hardware-failure, nas, desktop-computer, raid-1

Lets say I have a few HDDs in a RAID 1 array. From where will I know that one of my HDDs is dead? Is there some kind of automatic alert system or do I have to check it manually? If I have to check it by myself, how? Does the answer varies if the device is not a PC but a NAS?

Comment: @Ramhound, a raid 1 is a mirror, so no, it wouldn't. That is the point of mirroring drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be told unless there's a utility/facility to alert you, and it's configured.  Additionally if the RAID controller is hardware based it may display a warning ELD on the adapter. If it integrates fully with your chassis, you may get a warning light on the chassis (usually only server-grade stuff does this).

Otherwise you'll have to check its status manually every now and then.

For alerting, the solution you'd use, and how you configure it, would be totally dependant on the RAID controller/implementation you're using, and its support for your OS.